# How do I get access to the block contents of a custom Ember handlebars helper?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to write a custom Ember handlebars helper that will return some HTML, but I can't access the block contents within the helper.

Template:

```
{{#link}}
This is the block content
{{/link}}
```

Helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function (options) {
  var result = '<a href="http://example.com/">'
              + options.fn(this)
              + '</a>';
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

The result I'm expecting is: `<a href="http://example.com/">This is the block content</a>`

Instead I get: `This is the block content <a href="http://example.com/">undefined</a>`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/676/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it is currently possible to use block helpers in Ember.Handlebars easily. However, you could use a 'regular' Handlebars helpers like so:

```
{{link "This is the block content" url="http://www.example.com"}}
```

Helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function (value, options) {
    var result = '<a href="'+options.hash.url+'">'
                  + value
                  + '</a>';
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/680/).

Comment: I'm not sure whether to accept this as the answer or not -- it did actually solve my problem, but didn't really answer the question. According to http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html the 'question'-code should work.

Answer (score 1):

@chopper had the correct answer on how to do what it is you are looking for.  However, I just wanted to touch on the issue of Block Helpers to clear up their meaning.

Block helpers are used to determine rendering patterns of a block.  They are *not* "wrapping" helpers.

For example, a Block Helper you're undoubtedly familiar with is a simple {{#if}} helper.  This helper intakes a conditional, and uses that to either output the information contained within it, or not.  But it doesn't append information before/after the blocked section.

A more complex block helper would be the {{#each}} helper.  The each helper will iterate through a set and, by repeatedly calling options.fn(arrayItem), it will render the block multiple times, on each iteration inputting new data into the designated handlebar tags.  *But those tags are necessary in order to input information*.